# Which is faster, For Loop or .hasOwnProperty?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, for-loop

I was working on a project where I needed to pull a list of excluded users out of a giant list of user data. It made me wonder if it is faster to use a double `for loop` with excluded id's in an `array`. Or if putting the id's in object properties and using `.hasOwnProperty()` is faster.

```
var mainList = LARGE JSON OBJECT OF DATA.
var eArray = ["123456","234567","345678","456789","012345"];
var eObject = {"123456":"0","234567":"0","345678":"0","456789":"0","012345":"0"};
```

Using the Double `For Loop` Approach:

```
for(i=0; i < mainList.length; i++){
    for(j=0; j < eArray.length; j++){
        if(mainList[i]['id'] === eArray[j]){
           //Do Something
        }
    }
}
```

Using the `.hasOwnProperty()` Approach:

```
for(i=0; i < mainList.length; i++){
    if(eObject.hasOwnProperty(mainList[i]['id'])){
       //Do Something
    }
}
```

I realize there are other ways to make the loops faster, like storing lengths in variables. I've tried to simplify this.

Thanks for any information.

Comment: Well, if you think about it. It would make sense that the `.hasOwnProperty() Approach` would be faster because of 1 less loop.

Comment: @Shawn31313 That is what I figured. But wasn't sure how the `.hasOwnProperty()` looped through the properties of the object.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you think about it, it would make sense that the `.hasOwnProperty()` approach would be faster because it uses only 1 `for loop`.

### WRONG

I was actually a little surprised. I was expecting the double loop to be slower. But I guess you can't under estimate the speed of a `for loop`.

#### Double Loop

While this to me would seem like the slowest, this actually ended up being the fastest benching at `7,291,083 ops/sec`

#### .hasOwnProperty()

I can see how this would be slower because functions are slower than statements. This benches at `1,730,588 ops/sec`

#### if..in

@Geuis answer included the if..in statement and thought I would test the speed of that which would seem the fastest but benching at `2,715,091 ops/sec` it still doesn't beat the for loops.

#### Conclusion

For loops are fast. The double loops runs more than **4 times** faster than using `.hasOwnProperty()` and almost **3 times** faster than using the `if..in` condition. However, the performance is not really noticeable; so is speed really that important that you have the need to complicate things. In my opinion the `if..in` method is the way to go.

[Test this yourself](http://jsperf.com/stackoverflow-for-vs-hasownproperty) in your browser. I was using `Google Chrome 28`.

**Update**

It is important to note that using an `for..in` declaration will give you the best performance.

Comment: Added an alternative to `hasOwnProperty` to your jspref, which outperforms the double loop (~3 times faster)

Comment: I don't see anything added @EliasVanOotegem

Comment: This answer is incorrect and does not incorporate the fastest, and simplest, method that I put in my answer. Use indexOf with a val > -1 check. View the updated performance test here: http://jsperf.com/stackoverflow-for-vs-hasownproperty/5. A double loop is *always* going to be slower than a simpler, direct approach.

Comment: How is this answer incorrect. The Question Specifically asks `Which is faster, For Loop or .hasOwnProperty?`. I have answer that exact question. Now, good day sir.

Answer (score 8):

You've missed out on a third, faster alternative. Provided you haven't been tinkering with the `Object.prototype` in any way, and the ID's are unlikely to be prototype values (like `valueOf` and the like), you could simply use a `for` loop like so:

```
for(var i=0; i < mainList.length; i++)
{
    if (eObject[mainList[i].id] !== undefined)
    {//or typeof eObject[mainList[i].id] !== 'undefined'
        //do something
    }
}
```

Check [the updated JSPref](http://jsperf.com/stackoverflow-for-vs-hasownproperty/2), it's the fastest way *by far* (57,252,850 ops/sec vs 17,503,538 ops/sec for the double loop)

Comment: What if `eObject[mainList[i].id]` equals 0?All of the eObject's values equal 0 at the moment.

Comment: @Shawn31313: added extra check for that, edited JSPref to reflact that, too

Comment: if eObject does not contain null you can use (!eObject[mainList[i].id]) 2x faster also cache the length in for loop

Comment: @cocco: That's up to the OP to decide. I don't know what the object may or may not contain...

Comment: EDIT: Just noticed your `valueOf` comment. I said nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Edit to show the proper code for future internet traversers: Visit http://jsperf.com/stackoverflow-for-vs-hasownproperty/5 for the comparison

```
var testVal = 'BigBrownFox',
    arr = [1,4,'asd','BigBrownFox',9];

if( arr.indexOf('testVal') > -1 ){
    //do something
}
```

For testing an array of values for existence in another array:

```
var testVal = ['BigBrownFox'],
    arr = [1,4,'asd','BigBrownFox',9];

for(var i=0, len=testVal.length; i<len; i++){

    if( arr.indexOf(testVal[i]) > -1 ){
        //do something
    }

}
```

Actually, your approach in both cases is slightly off.

If are using an array, just use the [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) function. If the testing value exists, it will return its index. Otherwise it's -1 if not found. No loop is needed at all.

In the case of an object, you don't use .hasOwnProperty. Yeah, it does what you want but its overcomplicated and slower because you're doing a function call.

Just use

```
var eObject = {"123456":"0","234567":"0","345678":"0","456789":"0","012345":"0"};
if( '234567' in eObject ){ //do something }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: From your link: "_indexOf is a recent addition to the ECMA-262 standard; as such it may not be present in all browsers..._"

Answer (score 0):

in chrome the fastest loop is for

in older/other browsers the fastest one is the while-- loop.

especially if you cache the length.(very important if the mainList is big)

as i see you have only strings in eObject i also suggest to use `(eObject[mainList[i].id])`

which is faster than `(eObject[mainList[i].id] !== undefined)`

```
var i=mainList.length;
while(i--){
  if (eObject[mainList[i].id]) {
    //do something
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you have any evidence to back up any of these claims?

Comment: give me some minutes and i run it through ubuntu mac windows ,firefox safari chrome ie mobile

Comment: ok tested on some system ... looks like that the only wired results come from firefox on ubuntu where if in is the winner.As for my claims i think i'm right yeah.

Comment: I was wondering if you had ever done any benchmarking to confirm that it makes a difference if you cache the length of an array.  You claim that it's **very** important, while I'd be suprised if it makes any difference at all.

Comment: yeah it makes a difference... especially on big arrays on older browsers... if u don't cache every single time it has to check the length of the array. but in chrome and modern browsers they prolly added an automatic caching system cause most ppl can't write in javascript

Comment: I understand the logic, but didn't expect any differce (because I assumed there would be some JIT optimization).  However, a quick google reveals [this](http://jsperf.com/caching-array-length/4), which shows I was wrong (as usual).

Comment: the parts of the for loop for (1.executes at start,2.executes every time,3.executes every time)

Comment: Ah yeah... I know how a for loop works.  As I said, I assumed that the JIT compiler would optimize things regardless of whether or not you cache the length.

Comment: like i said on modern browsers it's almost not noticable and the for loop is faster than the while... which is also strange...while was always the fastest one.nothing to check besides it reaches 0.

Comment: Code gets optimized as it's compiled and/or run, so that doesn't surprise me at all.

Comment: this tests are all written wrong.1. you need a big array.2.if you cache u you should cache the length in the preparation code.in the examples even if they cache the lengththe jsperf function caches the length thousends of times.and loops through an array of 5 items ... lol

Comment: you also can't cache the while loop in jsperf.

Comment: Do you fail to see that I'm agreeing with you?  I provided the link to the jsPerf results as evidence that I was wrong and you were correct.  To quote myself: "_However, a quick google reveals this [link], which shows I was wrong (as usual)..._"

Comment: yeah but the examples in jsperf don't proviede a correct use of it. they are written totally wrong...

Comment: i created a new one with an array of 10000 random numbers as a string.http://jsperf.com/loopscc

Comment: in realworld while wins